# How to get Graphite to simply count counters, not time-rate them

Tags: graphite, collectd, graphite-carbon

I'm using Graphite and Collectd to monitor my server. In particular, I'm using the [tail](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Tail) pluggin to count failed SSH logins. I'm using a counter for this metric, so expect to see 1, 2, 3, 0, etc... for data points. However, what I'm seeing is 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0, etc... It seems to me like Graphite is providing counts-per-second. I say this because my retention policy is one data point every 10 seconds for two hours. So 1 failed login per 10 seconds = 0.1 per second. I'm looking at this in a graph. It looks like this:

[image]

Furthermore, when I scale out to the next retention level, the numbers get adjusted accordingly: so 1 failed login which was shown as 0.1 is now shown as much less than this: 0.017 or something.

I don't think this is related to the aggregation method used: even the finest data is off. How can I get Graphite to treat this metric as a pure, raw, counter?

Here's my storage-schemas.conf (the retention policy):

```
[my_server]
pattern = .*
retentions = 10s:2h,1m:2d,30m:400d
```

Here's my configuration of the collectd tail plugin:

```
<Plugin "tail">
    <File "/var/log/auth.log">
            Instance "auth"
            <Match>
                    Regex "sshd[^:]*: Failed password"
                    DSType "CounterInc"
                    Type "counter"
                    Instance "sshd-invalid_user"
            </Match>
    </File>
</Plugin>
```

And here's my configuration of the write_graphite pluggin (which sends data to graphite):

```
<Plugin write_graphite>
    <Node "my_server_name">
            Host "localhost"
            Port "2003"
            Protocol "tcp"
            LogSendErrors true
            Prefix "collectd."
            #Postfix ""
            StoreRates true
            AlwaysAppendDS false
            EscapeCharacter "_"
    </Node>
</Plugin>
```

I tried setting `StoreRates false` for the write_graphite pluggin, but this didn't work. It did change the behaviour: when I performed a single failed SSH login, that metric shows as 1. However, it didn't drop back down to 0. When I performed two more failed logins, the metric pops up to 3.

Also of interest: I've also loaded the users pluggin which simply shows the number of users logged in and it's working great: shows 1 when I SSH in, two when I SSH in again, and back to 1 when I exit one SSH. For both settings of StoreRates. So it seems like what I want is possible somehow. Maybe not with the tail pluggin though.

The SSH logins with `StoreRates false` along with correct behaviour for Users Logged in can be seen in these graphs:

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although swissunix's answer is very helpful, to achieve the behaviour I was looking for, I ended up using [Logster](https://github.com/etsy/logster) instead of Collectd. With Logster, you write the bit of code that parses the file as well as the bit that returns the metric. So although dividing a count by the time is common with Logster, you don't have to do this if you don't want to: there's lots of flexibility.

I've put my parsers here: https://github.com/camlee/logster-parsers

Answer (score 3):

You are asking the system to count the number of events. And this is exactly what it's doing: it's counting the number of failed logins since its startup. Whether you're using `StoreRates` or not simply changes the way that information is displayed: as a rate or as the raw counter. A counter may never decrease! What you're actually asking for is a counter that resets itself upon reading: count the number of failed logins since the last time collectd checked.

As it happens the `ABSOLUTE` data source type in rrdtool can be used to achieve this, but that won't help you.

Step back, and think about what you're trying to achieve: the number of failed logins per second seems to me like a perfectly sane metric!

Comment: You're right. Thanks for the perspective. So what I'm asking for then is for the metric to be a gauge. The tail pluggin doesn't support this for counting lines. Maybe I'll look into other pluggins.

Comment: I can see how the rate of failed logins makes sense on a high-volume system, but for me, I'll be getting low enough numbers that it's not as intuitive as a resetting-counter: when I'm looking at aggregated data for a minute, I can understand 4 more easily than 4/60 = 0.067. I also find that graph axis labels don't scale well to small numbers like this: I'm seeing graphs with 0.0 for each tick. Maybe if I choose better retention periods, this would be better. For example by making them all factors of 10.

Comment: Where do you see that the "rate" stored with StoreRate as true is "per second"? I can't find this documented anywhere.

Comment: The [types.db manpage](https://collectd.org/documentation/manpages/types.db.5.shtml) mentions that the data sources used by collectd are inspired by rrdtool. The referenced [rrdcreate manpage](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdcreate.en.html) explicitly mentions that COUNTER and DERIVE types are "stored as a per-second rate"

Answer (score 2):

If you set StoreRates to false, in graphite you can apply the derivative function to the ever-increasing counter to get your rate of increase per retention interval, which would match your requirement.

E.g. in your example of reporting 1 failed login, then 2, you saw the values 1 and 3. The derivative is 1 and 2: the failed logs per interval that graphite tracks.